# chat page on jquery mobile

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

I am trying to create a very simple chat page on jquery mobile, with the following page schema:

```
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
    <h1>Chat with...</h1>
</div><!-- /header -->

<div data-role="content">
    <div id="chatcontents"></div><input type="text" />
</div><!-- /content -->

<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
    Footer
</div><!-- /footer -->
```

with the div "chatcontents" to contain all the messages, and the input text to be at the bottom.

The problem is that jquery mobile sort of overrides my css settings, so it does not work out to be textbox at the bottom (considering the footer) and "chatcontents" to occupy the rest of the screen with the text starting from the bottom.

Anybody already tried this already?

Thanks in advance.